# Going from test/staging to release server with teamcity

Tags: .net, svn, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

Currently we are using team city for automatic testing and deployment to a test/staging server. Our solution consists of several .net web api:s and mvc projects which are sharing a common domain. The workflow is as follows (simplified):

1. Developer checks in his changes to svn
2. Teamcity runs an msbuild script that takes care of config transforms, testing and packaging of the solution. The solution is then deployed to the test server (if the tests pass).

This works really nice but we are unsure on how to best deploy to our release server and how the workflow should look like. Imagine that we have big "Do Release" button. What steps should then follow? Since the question is very vague I have tried to make it more concrete with the following questions:

1. When the button is pressed we would like to tag the current svn root. Is this possible with team city or should I go the other way around, that is, create a tag and let team city use this instead of the root? If so, how do I tell team city which tag to use?
   Or should I use the latest build artifacts instead?
2. Related to 1. How do I handle versioning (naming) of the release artifacts/tag?
3. Is there for some reason bad practice to use msdeploy to deploy the solution to our release server? Should I consider handling the deployment step manually?
4. Should database migrations be handled manually?

What else should I consider?

**Edit:**
I found [this](http://www.laurentkempe.com/post/build-and-deployment-automation-vcs-root-and-labeling-in-teamcity.aspx) blogpost which answers the question on how to create automatic tagging/labeling of a svn trunk.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing a similar situation.

**One way: build chains in TeamCity**

One way of resolving it is to add a build chain, where your second build config is based on the first build config. You do this (in TeamCity 7/8) by:

1. adding a second build configuration
2. specifying a Snapshot Dependency in the Dependencies tab
3. specifying artifact dependencies if needed in the Dependencies tab (and mark them "Build from the same chain" to use the upstream artifacts.

Do not add a build trigger to your second build configuration; you then must click `Run` on it to allow it to go.

This also allows you to pull in configs and data from different repositories if you need.

What I don't know though is how much control you have over who can push the run button... it seems so far that anyone that can log in and see the project will have that ability.

See the [TeamCity 7](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Chain) or [TeamCity 8](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Chain) documentation on build chains for more info.

**Alternative Approach**

In the end this gets a bit messy, so I'm looking at [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview) instead to take over the workflow part of it; TeamCity will still handle the builds, BuildMaster will take care of the promotions and deployments.